# var x="<?php echo strtotime($uEvents['start']);?>"; gives a different result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, strtotime

i want to pass php datetime to javascript using this code:

```
var x="<?php echo strtotime($uEvents['start']);?>";
```

but the **value** of **unix timestamp** is different (`database value is "2014-03-25 08:36:15"`)

```
echo strtotime($uEvents['start'])] ==> 1395711375<br/>
var x ==> 1395711287
```

i've search about this difference, but it seems not because javascript is milliseconds and php is in seconds

Comment: Simply append `'000'` string to timestamp

Comment: ^ because Javascript tends to handle timestamps in [milliseconds not seconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Comment: FWIW, I recommend using an ISO 8601 format through-and-through as it is much easier for humans to read which can minimize silly mistakes like this. (Plus, it can handle time-zone offsets, which are dreadfully useful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this problem caused by difference in time between server and client (which is about 1.5 minutes).

If you want client to get the same time as server pass try this:

```
var d = new Date("<?php echo $uEvents['start']; ?>");  //Date constructor can
                                             //parse datetime passed as a string

console.log(d.toString());   //this will output time you need
```

You can also get millisecond timestamp:

```
var timestamp = d.getTime();
```

as well as hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();
```

Comment: sorry, but i still develop this on localhost. php return right value, but only on javascript there's an additional 7 hours. im affraid that javascript automatically added my GMT +07. hour on php: date("H",1395711375) ==> 01 and hour  on jsc: new Date(x*1000) ==> 08

Comment: Take a look at [`date_default_timezone_set` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). You may set timezone on server side with it

Comment: thanks for your reply. I can not do that, I want this application can be used by someone else with a different timezone. not for my region only